# Topology not smooth and trying to work with a 6 pole

Tags: topology

I have this situation

[image]

I want to smooth off the edges so with some basic cuts I get

[image]

With a sub-d of 2 applied

[image]

I have played around with this for too long trying to find a solution. I know the problem is the pole and I have had so many crazy topology solutions that honestly became unworkable.

Any suggestions would be very welcome

thank you

Here is another image to show the 6 pole

[image]

Changed the topology based on comments (thank you) and there is an improvement. Makes sense to add a loop Any other suggestions would be great - thanks

[image]

added autosmooth at 50

[image]

[image]

Additional edge loop added

Seems so far this is the best I can achieve?

[image]

[image]

[image]

In response to comment on the issue. The light looks wrong on this image and slightly creased. thanks

[image]

*FINAL SOLUTION*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The point is we don't know where you want to go and what the final result should look like.

Comment: Thanks - I would like it to be smooth all around. With the mat cap on there you can see the light looks a bit off as if it is slightly creased. Added another image on orig question at the end - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve the problem adding some kind of inset around the pole.

Like this:

[image]

[image]

If you want to adjust the sharpness around the pole, select the 12 surrounding vertices and use G G to edge slide more or less closer to the pole.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I have updated my original question with more images.

Answer (score 2):

After some attempts, I solved the issue.

Make some loops as closely as possible but the weird thing is still there.

Add a **Multiresolution** Modifier and subdivide it once.

Now the corners are very sharp as you can see in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you LeoNas. I added to my original question with my final solution. I was looking for a smoother more rounded edge rather than sharp. I will use your solution for a sharper version - thank you

Answer (score 1):

This solution looks good, you need additional edge loops though:

[image]

Comment: Thank you moonboots. Initially I thought about the 6 pole but due to the topology there is no getting away from it as those edges can't really move. Given its shape I think (at the moment) the solutions shown (yours and Lemon) are the best we can get. The loop/edge ring on my final solution is only holding back the 6 pole and keeping it from doing further damage on the mesh. I could put it tighter but found that it looks very creased so it was a trial and error to get the best I could. thanks again